# Importing Scheduled Tasks with Powershell in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am very new to Powershell scripting but have attempted to modify a script that I found [here](http://jon.netdork.net/2011/03/10/powershell-and-importing-xml-scheduled-tasks/) to import some XML Scheduled Tasks using Powershell in Windows 2012 R2.

I have been successful in importing the Scheduled Tasks into the root [Task Scheduler Library] using this script.

The problem seems to be that the Schedule Tasks need to be imported into a subfolder under Task Scheduler Library, let's say "SubTasks"

```
$task_path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\ST Testing\exported ST's\scheduledTask.xml"
$task_user = "usr"
$task_pass = "pwd"

$schedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service")
$schedule.Connect("server") # servername
#$folder = $schedule.GetFolder("\") <===This works fine
$folder = $schedule.GetFolder("\SubTasks") #<===This does not work
Write-Host $folder

Get-Item $task_path | % {
   $task_name = $_.Name.Replace('.xml', '')
   $task_xml = Get-Content $_.FullName
   $task = $schedule.NewTask($null)
   $task.XmlText = $task_xml
   $folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task_name, $task, 6, $task_user, $task_pass, 1, $null)
```

}

When I run the above Powershell Script I receive this error:

> Exception calling "RegisterTaskDefinition" with "7" argument(s): "The 
>   specified path is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700A1)"
>   At C:\Users\me\Desktop\ST Testing\ImportSTs.ps1:22 char:5
>   +     $folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task_name, $task, 6, $task_user, 
>   $task_pass, ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the path exist yet?

Comment: similar requirement, had to support ps v2 as well, so I choose to use `schtasks` - my solution: https://bitbucket.org/trginternational/trg.hhc.autobackup/raw/master/ScheduleBackup.ps1

Comment: Yes, if you mean does the subtask [\Subtask] folder exist. It has been created in Task Scheduler.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get this to work for our needs.

```
$task_user="username"
$task_pass="password"
$schedule=new-object -ComObject ("Schedule.Service")
$schedule.Connect("server")
$folder=$schedule.GetFolder("\tasks")
$path="\\server\c$\temp\Tasks\"
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.xml"| foreach {
$task_conf=Get-Item -Path $_.FullName
$taskname=$task_conf.Name
$task_xml=$task_conf.FullName
$task=$schedule.NewTask(0)
$task.XmlText=(Get-Content $task_xml).Replace('Task version="1.1" xmlns','Task version="1.2" xmlns')
$folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($taskname,$task,6,$task_user,$task_pass,1,$null)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Register-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps) supports using XML to define the task:

```
Register-ScheduledTask `
    -User $task_user `
    -Password $task_pass `
    -TaskName ([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($task_path)) `
    -TaskPath '\SubTasks' `
    -Xml (Get-Content $task_path -Raw)
```

Note that you need to fetch the actual XML *content*. The `-Raw` flag prevents `Get-Content` from returning a `String[]`, which also makes `Register-ScheduledTask` unhappy.

Also note that `Register-ScheduledTask` has a `-TaskPath` argument, allowing you specify a subfolder to put the task in if desired.

I'm not fond of using the grave mark for line continuation, so I prefer splatting to spread things out over multiple lines:

```
$taskArgs = @{
    User='usr';
    Password='pwd';
    TaskName=([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($task_path));
    TaskPath='\SubTasks';
    Xml=(Get-Content $task_path -Raw)
}

Register-ScheduledTask @taskArgs
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're on powershell 3 (win2k12 - so you are) and above, there is a whole module for task scheduling.

see: `gcm -Module PSScheduledJob`

however, it does not seem to come with an easy way to import tasks from xml.

there are modules for that, [this particular module](https://www.petri.com/export-import-powershell-scheduled-jobs) deserializes the xml file and tests for all settings, seems more cumbersome than schtasks solution listed below.

for powershell 2 (win2k8) I found it easier to use `schtasks` - full ref here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

for example (scheduling a task from an xmlfile, the task will run under a particular user creds:

```
schtasks /Create /XML $xmlfile /RU $creds.UserName /RP $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password /TN "My Task Name"
```

I got my xml file by manually creating the task and exporting to xml (I removed credential and info nodes from xml)